# how to change the shape of a numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a 28x28 picture which I want to convert to a numpy array with the shape `(1, 28, 28)`. First I am doing reshaping which gives me `(3,28,28)` and when i try flattening it outputs `(2352,)` which is *28 * 28 * 3.* I have no idea what i am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

This is the code i am doing:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('Datasets/Tumor_28_28/no/no0.jpg')

print('image size: ', image.size)

numpydata = np.asarray(image)
numpydata = numpydata.reshape(-1, 28, 28)

print('numpydata: ', numpydata.shape)

flat = numpydata.flatten()

print('shape: ', flat.shape)
print(flat)
```

This outputs:

```
image size:  (28, 28)
numpydata:  (3, 28, 28)
shape:  (2352,)
[3 3 3 ... 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you called `reshape` on `numpydata`, I bet its `shape` was `(28, 28, 3)`, where the 3 is for the 3 RGB color channels. If you really only want one channel, you need to convert the image to grayscale first.

If your reaction is "but it is grayscale!", then the 3 RGB channels actually contain the same data, and you can write `numpydata = numpydata[...,0]` to select one channel

Comment: Thank you so much! Converting it to grayscale worked!